# Android Data Binding comparison in xml

Tags: android, data-binding

im wondering whether i can do this comparison with databinding or not .. i want the field to have an inputmask based on the lenght of the numbers im getting so this is what im trying to do >

```
app:inputMask="@{state.capacity.length() > 3 ? InputMask.TON : InputMask.KG}"
```

but this isnt quite working as i planned out , i wanted to do liek an IF , if capacity lenght >3 then do this if not do that ..
but i think the ? means if its null and not true.. so any clue on how to achieve that ?

Comment: Which library are you using for `app:inputMask`?

Comment: its not a lib, its a dataBinding feature, you can create dataBinding adapters however you like.
more on : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use databinding adapter.

```
@BindingAdapter("myInputMask")
fun setMyInputMask(maskedEditText: MaskedEditText?, capacity: Int?) {
    if (capacity > 3) {
        editText.setMask(InputMask.TON)
    } else {
        editText.setMask(InputMask.KG)
    }
}
```

`app:myInputMask="@{state.capacity.length()}"`

Comment: that looks amazing thank you im gonna try it .. however i have a question , do i need to pass maskedEditText: MaskedEditText? as parameter even if i end up ont using it ? 
also, i was going to approach the matter this way, but this only helps right as the screen is renedered,i need to validate the field at all times , as the user types, so im going with addTextChangedListener and decimalFormat

Comment: The purpose is actually to change it depending on the capacity value. If you can continue with addTextChangedListener. But you will provide what you need on the first load.